# Does chances of specific training scale the same way that food does?

Tags: magikarp-jump

I noticed that the food that occurs most frequently is the food that gives the lowest JP, regardless of where the food is located on the list. I know this to be true because I leveled up my Oran Berry to have more JP than my Sitrus Berry and then suddenly the Sitrus Berries occurred more frequently than the Oran Berries.

My question is: does training do the same thing?

By the time I realized this about the food I had been focusing on leveling the training session that was the farthest down on the list (like Pokeball Smash). I know that a training session like Pokeball Smash already felt rare to me, but would I be harming myself in leveling just one training session? Would that training session scale so that every other session is more frequent? Would I be better off leveling training evenly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Training definitely does not work in the *exact* same way.

Food works as such:

- Every 4 seconds: if there is no food currently out, then put the lowest JP Food item
- Every 15 seconds: put a random Food item

Training doesn't have any such mechanism, so no, it does not scale in the same manner.

I do believe that training does have a higher chance of giving you a lower JP training, though.  It's not clear exactly how that relationship works, nor is it explicit in the game in any way.  I leveled all of my trainings to rank 50 (up through Balloon, where I stopped buying new ones), and in that process saw more Balloons than I was used to while it had the lower JP count (when Sandbag and Jump Trainer hit 50 and were suddenly the highest JP).  I haven't done a thorough study though, as the N size is too small.

Comment: Anecdotally, I feel like the mid level training happens the most, but I've not kept careful track. I think I'll start keeping a log and see how it compares to your theory.

Comment: I'll add my anecdote to the list: I power-levelled Sandbag Slam to 75 while my others sat at 50 or below. Sandbag Slam easily out-JP'd the other training sessions, and suddenly seemed to become very rare. Over the past week since I did it, I haven't upgraded any other Training beyond 50 (been focussing on food) but Sandbag Slam remains the rarest of my training sessions.